# box shadow & border radius bug chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

Just found another bug in chrome when using `border-radius` and `box-shadow`.

Hard to explain it, Look at the picture below.

- The first box is fine and has a radius of `53px`.
- the second box loses its shadow on the corner, to me it looks like the shadow is now square but is being hidden with a `overflow: hidden` **effect** the radius of this box is `54px`.
- now the last box is screwed, the shadow looks the same as the second box, only not being hidden by the `overflow:hidden` **effect**, the radius of this box is `56px`. 
  [image]
  Check out a demo for yourself, it works fine in **Firefox**, The problem is in **Chrome**

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RmYea/1/**

Can anyone shed any light on this, why it happens?

**CSS**:

```
div{
    height:50px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 5px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px inset;
}

div:nth-child(1){
     border-top-left-radius: 53px;   
}

div:nth-child(2){
     border-top-left-radius: 54px;   
}

div:nth-child(3){
     border-top-left-radius: 56px;   
}
```

**Note: This only happens with `inset`**

Comment: What do you mean when you ask "why it happens"? All I can say is that this is definitely a bug because shadows are always expected to be rounded according to the corner radii given by `border-radius`, whether inset or outset, and not clipped as Chrome is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some bugs to manage border-radiu.
In your case doesn't manage well the border, to solve this problem you have to change your logic I think because is a bug recognized of border-radius

See this link of something like your problem (not the same problem but some cases about bug in chrome like yours):
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82417
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30475

Comment: There is no `overflow:hidden;` being used.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that the border-radius has some bug into chrome, if you seen into second case the problem is a little bit visible not only in the third div @Pinocchio

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I confirm I am not answering the original question, in the true sense, but I see this problem a little *differently*.

I would question the values being used for the `border-radius` in the first place.

The height of your `<div>` is `50px`, therefore your `border-radius` value shouldn't be more than `50px` ( this will provide a full height curve ).

**Examples:** http://jsfiddle.net/WWvxV/

Following the above, both browsers render the element as expected.

Again, I agree there is an issue with handling values that are larger than can be applied in Chrome, but I also think your initial values need revision.